Ordenar por campo de texto
tengo una tabla de sorteos,tengo unos campos en los que se guarda la hora de cierre,de lunes a domingo,estos campos son de tipo texto,debe quedar registrado por ejemplo de esta forma: 4:00 PM,lo que necesito es poder ordenarlos de menor a mayor,en un principio tengo esta consulta $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY '$cierre' DESC "); donde $cierre puede ser cierre_lunes,cierre_ martes etc.. ,el código completo que uso es el siguiente:
<?php
 $baseURL = 'getGanadores.php';

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY '$cierre' DESC ");

if($query->num_rows > 0){?>
<div class="table-responsive" id="dataContainer">
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr> 
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Hora/cierre</th>
<th>Activo</th>
<th>Ganadores</th>
<th>Asignar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row["fecha_cierre"]; ?></td>
<td><?= $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
<?php 
switch ($cierre) 
{
  case 'cierre_lunes':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_lunes"];
    break;
    case 'cierre_martes':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_martes"];
    break;
    case 'cierre_miercoles':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_miercoles"];
    break;
    case 'cierre_jueves':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_jueves"];
    break;
    case 'cierre_viernes':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_viernes"];
    break;
      case 'cierre_sabado':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_sabado"];
    break;
    case 'cierre_domingo':
    $respuesta = $row["cierre_domingo"];
    break;
  default:
    $respuesta = "El día especificado no es correcto";
    break;
}


?>
<td><?= $respuesta; ?></td>
<td><?= $row["estado"]; ?></td>
<td><?= $row["numeros_premiados"]; ?></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm asignar" data-id="<?= $row['id_sorteo_base']; ?>"><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button> </td>
</tr>
<?php
}

} else{
echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><h2>No hay registros</h2></td></tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

Gracias.

puedes hacer un: order by campo1, campo2,campo3 o si quieres un order by campo1 desc, campo2 asc, campo3 asc y asi...

Hola, de hecho ya tengo eso: $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY '$cierre' DESC "); como ves uso una variable que le llamé "cierre" el asunto es que no está funcionando @Bryro.

a simple vista parese que se pasa como string intenta asi:  "SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY ${cierre} DESC "; o "SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY {$cierre} DESC "; no recuerdo como es la sintaxis!

Funciona en la segunda forma:  {$cierre},muchas gracias @Bryro

puedes hacerlo asi:
nota: el error se da porque se pasa como string
solucion:
$query = $db->query(""SELECT * FROM sorteos_base ORDER BY {$cierre} DESC ");

ahora una pequeña mejora.
como tus llaves se llaman igual que tus columnas podemos eliminar el switch:
if (array_key_exists($cierre, $row)){
    $respuesta= $row[$cierre];
}else{
    $respuesta = "El día especificado no es correcto";
}


Buenísimo, muchas gracias @Bryro.

Mira,tengo otra duda,hay manera de establecer valores mínimo y máximo sobre un input de tipo text sin cambiarlo a tipo number ? @Bryro

@Samael tendrías que hacerlo con javascript por ejemplo, y realizar las validaciones necesarias, como que sea un número, y respete tus rangos, y lanzar un error en caso de no hacerlo.
